# bcp command load stripes

Tags: bcp

When I load from BCP in DOS/cmd, the process asks me about each column.  I choose character, no prefix, 50 length, | field terminator for all except the last field which I leave blank (the default terminator is none).  I've tried \n and | but both result in errors too.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  The data load fine in Excel, but bcp stripes.  I've confirmed the table has the same numbers of columns as the data file's header and data rows.

Here are the results of the import.
[image: SQL results pane with striped output]

The command I use is:

```
bcp dbname.dbo.tablename in "drive\path\filename.csv" -T -S servername
```

Any guidance appreciated.